# net-module does't react when pulling cable within embedded Linux

Tags: node.js, sockets, connection, embedded-linux

i have a problem that I want to discuss.
I'm using the npm module nodes7 to communicate with a Siemens-PLC, an industrial computer for automating processes. NodeS7 uses the net-module to create a socket for the whole communication.

Now the problem:
I'm reading cyclic values from the plc. To simulate a connection error I pulled off the Ethernet cable. I tested the reaction of my software on three OS. Windows, Ubuntu VM and the destination system an embedded Linux OS. Each of them behave different. The Windows-OS and Ubuntu VM are stopping the communication which is good. In the emb. Linux nothing happens. I debugged the net module to see what's happening in it.

The following picture shows the log-files of each OS.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3fqQ.jpg)

left shell=Windows: after a Timeout of the nodeS7-library the net-module detects an ECONNRESET
middle shell=Ubuntu: after a Timeout of the nodeS7-library the net-module detects an EOF
right shell=embedded Linux: nothing is getting detected

When you have a look on the src-code of the net-module you can see that the debug-log onread is getting created within the onread-function. The on-read function is always called whenever the handle gets a buffer, or when there's an error reading. see [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/net.js#L531)

Well, I have a reading error. What I am doing wrong???
Any ideas?

Comment: How is the network interface on your embedded Linux system managed? Is there "something" that will react on the pulled cable (for example by deconfiguring the interface)?

Comment: The Ethernet PHY can detect when the cable is disconnected (i.e. broken link).  But getting a notification of such a specific event is a waste of effort.  You probably want a broader notification that covers any/all reasons of communication failure with the other host.

Comment: My OS is using the NetworkManager. Ling up/down is getting detected but for some reason the "message" that the connection is down is not reaching the net-module